# reusing fragments in a fragmentpageradapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-compatibility

I have a viewpager that pages through fragments. My `FragmentPagerAdapter` subclass creates a new fragment in the `getItem` method which seems wasteful. Is there a `FragmentPagerAdapter` equivalent to the `convertView` in the `listAdapter` that will enable me to reuse fragments that have already been created? My code is below.

```
public class ProfilePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    ArrayList<Profile> mProfiles = new ArrayList<Profile>();

    public ProfilePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    /**
     * Adding a new profile object created a new page in the pager this adapter is set to.
     * @param profile
     */
    public void addProfile(Profile profile){
        mProfiles.add(profile);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mProfiles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new ProfileFragment(mProfiles.get(position));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The `FragmentPagerAdapter` already caches the `Fragments` for you. Each fragment is assigned a tag, and then the `FragmentPagerAdapter` tries to call `findFragmentByTag`. It only calls `getItem` if the result from `findFragmentByTag` is `null`. So you shouldn't have to cache the fragments yourself.

Comment: Bat I think that this is not solution. I have similar problem. I have 10 screens in ViewPager which all contain the same fragment only with different arguments. I don't need 10 instances. 3 is enought. When user scroll to right, most left fragment can be reused.

Comment: @ATom - when you scroll, fragments further than +/- 1 index are destroyed and recreated when you navigate to them anyway. Try putting a log output into the `onCreateView`method to see when each fragment is instantiated

Comment: @MattTaylor if you are using a ViewPager you can use setOffscreenPageLimit to keep the same instances

Comment: @MattTaylor - this is slightly incorrect. The fragment's themselves should not be destroyed (unless your app is running low on available memory), however that is different than the fragment views being destroyed (which will happen as soon as the fragment in question is beyond the OffscreenPageLimint). Add a 2nd log statement to your Fragment's onCreate and you'll see it should not called every time onCreateView gets called.

Comment: Fragment onCreateView method is the place where the data is set to the view. If getItem didn't called every time to create a new fragment. how the data for another Profile going to be set on a reused fragment!?

Comment: Also there is a getView method in the Fragment class and we can override it. shall we do this to reuse the same fragment with different data?

Comment: There's still no solution, right? Each solution still holds 10 fragments in memory after all. Instead of only 2 or 3.

Comment: it is important to mention that instances of your fragments should be committed to the `FragmentPagerAdapter` cache using `finishUpdate` method as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035090/how-to-get-existing-fragments-when-using-fragmentpageradapter/41345283#41345283

Answer (score 68):

Appendix for Geoff's post:

You can get reference to your `Fragment` in `FragmentPagerAdapter` using [`findFragmentByTag()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag(java.lang.String)). The name of the tag is generated this way:

```
private static String makeFragmentName(int viewId, int index)
{
     return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + index;
}
```

where viewId is id of ViewPager

Look at this link: http://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/browse/trunk/compatibility/AndroidSupportV2/src/android/support/v2/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.java#104

Comment: Note for people like me: viewId is the id of the ViewPager

Comment: @Kopfgeldjaeger I saw you code `getFragmentByPosition`. What is the position of fragment?

Comment: Seconding @GregEnnis does not work with State pager, any thoughts?

Comment: @trippedout @GregEnnis try [**my answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29287415/708906) below. You can save references to the `Fragments` created by `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and use those instead of trying to find them with `tags` (which `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` doesn't use).

Comment: first, the code in this answer depends on compatibility with the internal naming: if this mechanism changes, this code will stop to work. Second there's really no reason to obtain refs to Fragments by tag as you can simply store them when you call `instantiateItem` in your `onCreate` as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035090/how-to-get-existing-fragments-when-using-fragmentpageradapter/41345283#41345283

Answer (score 24):

Seems a lot of the people viewing this question are looking for a way to reference the `Fragments` created by `FragmentPagerAdapter`/`FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. I would like to offer my solution to this without relying on the *internally* created `tags` that the other answers on here use.

As a bonus this method should also work with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. See notes below for more detail.

---

### Problem with current solutions: relying on internal code

A lot of the solutions I've seen on this and similar questions rely on getting a reference to the existing `Fragment` by calling `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag()` and mimicking the [**internally created tag: `"android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + id`**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.java?av=f#173). The problem with this is that you're relying on internal source code, which as we all know is not guaranteed to remain the same forever. The Android engineers at Google could easily decide to change the `tag` structure which would break your code leaving you unable to find a reference to the existing `Fragments`.

### Alternate solution without relying on internal `tag`

Here's a simple example of how to get a reference to the `Fragments` returned by `FragmentPagerAdapter` that doesn't rely on the internal `tags` set on the `Fragments`. The key is to override [**`instantiateItem()`**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.java?av=f#83) and save references in there *instead* of in `getItem()`.

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
    private FragmentA m1stFragment;
    private FragmentB m2ndFragment;

    // other code in your Activity...

    private class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        // other code in your custom FragmentPagerAdapter...

        public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // Do NOT try to save references to the Fragments in getItem(),
            // because getItem() is not always called. If the Fragment
            // was already created then it will be retrieved from the FragmentManger
            // and not here (i.e. getItem() won't be called again).
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new FragmentA();
                case 1:
                    return new FragmentB();
                default:
                    // This should never happen. Always account for each position above
                    return null;
            }
        }

        // Here we can finally safely save a reference to the created
        // Fragment, no matter where it came from (either getItem() or
        // FragmentManger). Simply save the returned Fragment from
        // super.instantiateItem() into an appropriate reference depending
        // on the ViewPager position.
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Fragment createdFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            // save the appropriate reference depending on position
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    m1stFragment = (FragmentA) createdFragment;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    m2ndFragment = (FragmentB) createdFragment;
                    break;
            }
            return createdFragment;
        }
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        // do work on the referenced Fragments, but first check if they
        // even exist yet, otherwise you'll get an NPE.

        if (m1stFragment != null) {
            // m1stFragment.doWork();
        }

        if (m2ndFragment != null) {
            // m2ndFragment.doSomeWorkToo();
        }
    }
}
```

**or** if you prefer to work with `tags` instead of class member variables/references to the `Fragments` you can also grab the `tags` set by `FragmentPagerAdapter` in the same manner:
NOTE: this doesn't apply to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` since it doesn't set `tags` when creating its `Fragments`.

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Fragment createdFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    // get the tags set by FragmentPagerAdapter
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            String firstTag = createdFragment.getTag();
            break;
        case 1:
            String secondTag = createdFragment.getTag();
            break;
    }
    // ... save the tags somewhere so you can reference them later
    return createdFragment;
}
```

Note that this method does NOT rely on mimicking the internal `tag` set by `FragmentPagerAdapter` and instead uses proper APIs for retrieving them. This way even if the `tag` changes in future versions of the `SupportLibrary` you'll still be safe.

---

**Don't forget** that depending on the design of your `Activity`, the `Fragments` you're trying to work on may or may not exist yet, so you have to account for that by doing `null` checks before using your references.

**Also, if instead** you're working with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, then you don't want to keep hard references to your `Fragments` because you might have many of them and hard references would unnecessarily keep them in memory. Instead save the `Fragment` references in `WeakReference` variables instead of standard ones. Like this:

```
WeakReference<Fragment> m1stFragment = new WeakReference<Fragment>(createdFragment);
// ...and access them like so
Fragment firstFragment = m1stFragment.get();
if (firstFragment != null) {
    // reference hasn't been cleared yet; do work...
}
```

Comment: The first strategy he suggested with `m1stFragment = (FragmentA) createdFragment;` worked for me and I think it is the best solution here. For some reason the alternate strategy `String firstTag = createdFragment.getTag();` did not work for me. Thank you so much @Turbo, this saved me.

Comment: RE: problems with current solutions... 
It's worth noting, that if you're using the support library for fragments, then you're not actually relying on the device's "internal code" to do this. You'd be relying on the support library code which is shipped with your app (and you can even check the source into your repo if you're paranoid or need to make changes).

Comment: @geoff good point, but is this even a documented feature? Not to mention it looks bad - you have nice, meaningful function-based tags you define yourself... and then you have this.

Comment: as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035090/how-to-get-existing-fragments-when-using-fragmentpageradapter/41345283#41345283 there's really no reason to override `instantiateItem` to store references as you are supposed to _call_ `instantiateItem` in your `onCreate` so you can store a reference there by the way.

Answer (score 17):

If the fragment still in memory you can find it with this function.

```
public Fragment findFragmentByPosition(int position) {
    FragmentPagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter = getFragmentPagerAdapter();
    return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
            "android:switcher:" + getViewPager().getId() + ":"
                    + fragmentPagerAdapter.getItemId(position));
}
```

*Sample code for v4 support api.*

Comment: first, the code in this answer depends on compatibility with the internal naming: if this mechanism changes, this code will stop to work. Second there's really no reason to obtain refs to Fragments by tag as you can simply store them when you call instantiateItem in your onCreate as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035090/how-to-get-existing-fragments-when-using-fragmentpageradapter/41345283#41345283

Answer (score 1):

For future readers!

If you are thinking of reusing fragments with viewpager, best solution is to use [ViewPager 2](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-the-view-pager-2-86dbce06ff71), since **View Pager 2 make use of RecyclerView.**

- [Medium article - Exploring the View Pager 2](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-the-view-pager-2-86dbce06ff71)
- [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2)
- [Samples repo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-viewpager2)
- [Release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is (theoretically) not an answer to the question, but a different approach.

I had an issue where I needed to refresh the visible fragments. Whatever I tried, failed and failed miserably...

After trying so many different things, I have finally finish this using `BroadCastReceiver`. Simply send a broadcast when you need to do something with the visible fragments and capture it in the fragment.

If you need some kind of a response as well, you can also send it via broadcast.

cheers