# How to use Android Fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-adapter

I'm looking at some demo code that shows how to use a Fragment Adapter (Tab Adapter in this case). I'm curious as to what exactly the `instantiate()` method does. I see it used in the following demo code on this page:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

(see the `getItem()` method within the `TabsAdapter` class)

If I'm reading the demo code correctly, every time a user clicks on one of the tabs, a new Fragment is created? And thus the fragment starts the entire life-cycle again (`onAttach()`...`onCreate()`... etc)? This sounds awfully inefficient. I would think that the fragment that will represent the content for each tab should be instantiated only once (perhaps in the `addTab()` method), and then saved into some collection where it can be fetched when `getItem()` is called.

Please correct me if I'm mistaken in any of this. I'm trying to better understand how to manage fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find an explanation for my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7098081/135820)

Answer (score 0):

My money would be on that the `setCurrentItem()` function doesn't actually destroy the existing Fragment being shown in that tab.  Otherwise there's really not much of a reason for the adapter to have a List of available tabs. Likely, when you switch from one tab to another, `setCurrentItem()` just detaches the UI from the currently active Fragment (or calls its `onPause()` method) and then re-attaches the UI for the newly selected Fragment (or calls its `onResume()` method).

But, if you're in doubt, you could read the source :)

Hope it helps,
David