# Popular array list using Volley and move to the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-volley

how do I get the list of data that was populated by the volley request because the fragment is getting an empty list which has been instantiated in the main activity.

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private ViewPager pager;
private ViewPageAdapter adapter;
private SlidingTabLayout tabs;
private int numTabs = 2;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sendJsonRequest();

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    adapter =  new ViewPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),titles,numTabs);

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);

    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            //return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
            return ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.cgred);
        }
    });

    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    ////////////////////////////////////////



   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getList().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

This method makes the request for the web service data and populates the array with method parseJson

```
public void sendJsonRequest() {

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, BCWATCH, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            parseJson(response); // This method populates the list instantiated at the beginning of the main activity
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest); 

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Getting data...");
    progressDialog.show();

}
```

**The Fragment**

My fragment receives an empty list, I believe it is because of the asynchronous execution of the request, but how to get the full list in the fragment?

```
public class Tab1 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

HashMap<String, String> obj;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    list = ((MainActivity) getActivity() ).getList();

    if(list != null){
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Not null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        for (HashMap<String, String> entry : list) {
            Set<String> keys = entry.keySet();
            for (String key : keys) {
                String value = entry.get(key);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"key:"+key+" value:"+value,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can populate array list using constructor of fragment and set adapter there [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873709/populate-listview-on-fragment-after-async-done-from-activity) else you should make JSON request in fragment it self.

Comment: The second link is the same that first