# view, adapter, getActivity(), in fragment are all null

Tags: android, null, fragment

In my activity, I call a method which is inside of a `fragment` to update a `ListView` in the fragment. However, the `getActivity()` method returns null, the `listView` is null, the `adapter` is null too. But I can see the `listView` is being displayed. Why are they null?

Note:
I call `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(position)` to get the `fragment`. However, it will return a different instance. According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976027/reusing-fragments-in-a-fragmentpageradapter), I can reuse the fragment by `findFragmentByTag`.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: It looks like you're having two instances of your fragment type

Comment: I am using `fragmentPagerAdapter` in my activity, and using `adapter.getItem(position)` to get the fragment. So, it might lead to a different instance? @gunar

Answer (score 0):

It depends when you try to access your activity and listview. In Fragment's constructor all of these are not available since they are not built yet.

- Activity is available after `onActivityCreated()` callback is triggered
- ListView is available after `onViewCreated()` callback is triggered

Comment: Thank you for reply, but my `ListView` is visible when I check if they are null.