# Correctly to call function in fragment tab from parent fragment with FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

I have tabs created with `FragmentPagerAdapter`:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
static final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        return new SessionDetails();
    case 1:
        return new SessionScoreTable();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}}
```

I need to update one tab by clicking buttons on another one.

Parent `FragmentActivity` has:

```
fragSessionDetails = (SessionDetails) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(0);
```

and has `function`:

```
public void setSessionCompleted(){
    fragSessionDetails.processSessionCompleted();
}
```

which is called from another tab (`SessionScoreTable`).

`SessionDetails` tab has function:

```
    public void processSessionCompleted(){
    Log.d(TAG,"processSessionCompleted" );
        bSave.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

bSave is button.

In log I have `NullPointerException` on row - `bSave.setEnabled(false)`:

> 06-30 16:20:45.414: D/STS_SessionDetails(15876): processSessionCompleted
>   06-30 16:20:45.414: D/AndroidRuntime(15876): Shutting down VM
>   06-30 16:20:45.414: W/dalvikvm(15876): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b62d88)
>   06-30 16:20:45.414: E/AndroidRuntime(15876): Exception
>   06-30 16:20:45.414: E/AndroidRuntime(15876): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-30 16:20:45.414: E/AndroidRuntime(15876): Process: com.vvv.vvvvvvvvvvvvv, PID: 15876
>   06-30 16:20:45.414: E/AndroidRuntime(15876): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   06-30 16:20:45.414: E/AndroidRuntime(15876):    at com.vvv.vvvvvvvvvvvvv.SessionDetails.processSessionCompleted(SessionDetails.java:237)
>   06-30 16:20:45.414: E/AndroidRuntime(15876):    at com.vvv.vvvvvvvvvvvvv.Session.setSessionCompleted(Session.java:151)

It looks like I lost something but have no idea what.
Any help please.

Comment: try using **FragmentStateAdapter** instead of **FragmentPagerAdapter**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've got a solution.

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
static final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;
private SessionDetails fragSessionDetails;
private SessionScoreTable fragSessionScoreTable;

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        return new SessionDetails();
    case 1:
        return new SessionScoreTable();
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Fragment createdFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    // save the appropriate reference depending on position
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragSessionDetails = (SessionDetails) createdFragment;
            break;
        case 1:
            fragSessionScoreTable = (SessionScoreTable) createdFragment;
            break;
    }
    return createdFragment;
}

public SessionDetails getFragSessionDetails(){
    return fragSessionDetails;
}

public SessionScoreTable getFragSessionScoreTable(){
    return fragSessionScoreTable;
}}
```

and

```
    public void setSessionCompleted(){
    SessionDetails fragSessionDetails = mSectionsPagerAdapter.getFragSessionDetails();
    if (fragSessionDetails != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "fragSessionDetails");
        fragSessionDetails.processSessionCompleted();
    }
}
```

Idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/29287415/2881525

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
fragSessionDetails = (SessionDetails) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(0);
```

Is very bad approach. Better approach will be to access the Fragment in runtime by change the method:

```
public void setSessionCompleted(){
    ((SessionDetails) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(0)).processSessionCompleted();
}
```

Comment: why is it bad? If there are may functions which use the fragment, it's better  to create it once. Or I don't count s/th?

Comment: First of all it is bad because the FragmentAapter may replace the fragment in some case and the reference will be wrong. Second you got the null probably because you called (SessionDetails) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(0) before the adapter actually inflate the layout inside the ViewPager.

Comment: If my answer help to you I appreciate if you accept it.

Comment: If it would be the case I do not have a row "D/STS_SessionDetails(15876): processSessionCompleted" in the log. Thanks, I've tried but it has not fixed the problem.